# How to escape from the `Insert mode` undoing the changes done in this mode?

Tags: vim, editor, vi

I'm newbie to Vim editor, so I want to do this simple task more simple than I actually do.

### Scenario

When I made a mistake or I just testing some new commands in the `Insert mode` I wish I could escape from this to `Normal mode` without affecting the file.

### My solution

I left the `Insert mode` going back to `Normal mode` and press `u` to undo the changes.

### Question

There is a way to just leave the `Insert mode` without affecting the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to execute one normal command and then return to insert mode. So in this case, you could do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and then <kbd>u</kbd> to execute an undo and return to insert mode. See `:help i_CTRL-o`

Answer (score 3):

Well, not sure if vim has this by default. But vim is very powerful editor, and it supports keyboard mappings: you can "bind" some sequence of actions to some keystroke/sequence of keystrokes.

This is how you can do for your task. Type this in normal mode:`:inoremap <f2> <esc>u`
Now you can press F2 to exit insert mode undoing changes.
If you like this binding and want it to persist between editing sessions, just put the same text(without colon) into your `.vimrc` file: `inoremp <f2> <esc>u`

There is one problem with this binding though: if you don't do any changes in insert mode F2 won't act as plain , it will also undo previous change.